# Mongodb How To Aggregate But Only Include One Result Per Date Field?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to aggregate results but I need to include only 1 result per date/day. Here's how my query currently looks:

```
.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'community_stats',
            as: 'stats',
            let: { id: '$_id' },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: { $eq: ['$community', '$$id'] },
                },
              },
              { $sort: { date: -1 } },
              { $limit: 5 },
            ],
          },
        },
      ])
```

Which returns an array like this:

```
stats: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("613d42f20e8023815b8f0ad3"),
      community: new ObjectId("6138ef0a00895c22c6cd3b68"),
      data: [Object],
      date: 2021-09-11T23:59:46.998Z
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("613b784e564ee6ad3e2dbb14"),
      community: new ObjectId("6138ef0a00895c22c6cd3b68"),
      data: [Object],
      date: 2021-09-10T15:22:54.764Z
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("6139f9487e4c964ef9dafd11"),
      community: new ObjectId("6138ef0a00895c22c6cd3b68"),
      data: [Object],
      date: 2021-09-09T12:08:40.198Z
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("6139f6eac570e66aa60a8b5f"),
      community: new ObjectId("6138ef0a00895c22c6cd3b68"),
      data: [Object],
      date: 2021-09-09T11:58:34.463Z
    }
  ]
```

Does anybody know how this can be done?

Comment: Please provide sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to add a [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage where you group the matches by date, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "community_stats",
      as: "stats",
      let: {
        id: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$community",
                "$$id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              year: {
                "$year": "$date"
              },
              month: {
                "$month": "$date"
              },
              day: {
                "$dayOfMonth": "$date"
              },
              
            },
            first: {
              $first: "$$ROOT"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$first"
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            date: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 5
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V6uE8kI7a5l)

In my example is used `$first` to select the first document from each day, you can however use different operators / logic if it needs to be changed.